# Count minimum no. of operations required to make first character and last character equal

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

We can do only two operations:
 1.Remove a letter from the beginning of the string.
 2.Remove a letter from the end of the string.

I have written following code for above question:

```
var f=function(s1){
  if(s1[s1.length-1]===s1[0]){
    return 0;
  }
  if(s1[s1.length-2]===s1[0]||s1[s1.length-1]===s1[1])
    {
      return 1;
    //document.write("hsdh");
    }

  else
    return 1+Math.min(f(s1.substring(1),f(s1.substring(0,s1[s1.length-1]))));
}
```

Code gives desired output for many testcases but for string "bacdefghipalop" it gives 9 as answer instead of 4 which is right answer.
Can you tell me where my code is going wrong?

Edit:- Actually I want to return the minimum no. of times we have to use above given operation to make the first character and last character of string equal.My code is giving right output for many testcases but for some reason it is giving wrong answer for s1="bacdefghipalop".What is pattern in input for which my code is giving wrong answer?Where can I improve my code to include these patterns to give right answer for each input.

Comment: [here](https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/good-string-2/description/)  is a link to problem.

Comment: Please add everything that is relevant for the question/problem **in the question itself**. For a better understanding of the requirement/problem some test cases and their output would help.

Comment: i'll remember that next time .

Comment: Not _"next time"_, now. Please edit your question ([_"edit"_ link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57412473/edit) is below your question) and add all relevant infos.

Comment: recursion would time out I think.

Comment: This method is super slow, but should work.  It doesn't work, because your function returns the wrong answer for "", "a", and "ab", for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this can explain where your function misfired. (replace the current content, with the following lines). They are mostly the same, but with a little blurb each, since you wanted to understand where yours went wrong.

If the string is/has become pointless to check, nothing more can be done:

```
  if (s1.length <= 1) return 0;
```

If first equals last, nothing more needs to be done:

```
  else if (s1[0] == s1[s1.length - 1]) return 0;
```

Otherwise, it's one down and check next level:

```
  else return 1 + Math.min(f(s1.substring(1)), f(s1.substring(0, s1.length - 1)));
```

I just adjusted the function as you wrote it, so if continue on this path I would use decreasing indices instead of creating smaller and smaller strings. Though string handling is relatively fast anymore, doing large strings or many, is costly. I would also avoid recursion. Go with something like what @Jagan_ explained, which is akin to how many other string operations (e.g. Levenshtein Distance, etc).

Comment: thanx Rob.that's what i wanted to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform this is using a hashmap in linear time and that too worst case will be O(N) where N is length of string when all characters are distinct.

Use 2 pointers one from left end and another from right end and traverse simultaneously and store the character in hashmap with its index.

If a character is already in hashmap than its just simple math on indexes.

```
s = input()
mp = dict()
n = len(s)
left,right=0,n-1
mini = n -1
while left < right:
    if s[left] not in mp:
        mp[s[left]] = left
        left += 1
    else:
        index = mp[s[left]]
        mini = left + n - 1 - index
        break
    if s[right] not in mp:
        mp[s[right]] = right
        right -= 1
    else:
        index = mp[s[right]]
        mini = index + n-1-right
        break
print(mini)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to create something which seems to work for the inputs you suggested , but I'm not sure it is what you really want.

You can try my code here:

```js
function testNumberOfOperations(str) {
  if (str[0] === str[str.length - 1]) {
    return 0;
  }

  var result = -1;

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
    var letter = str[i];

    var firstIndex = str.indexOf(letter);
    var lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf(letter);

    if (firstIndex !== lastIndex) {
      var operations = Math.abs(str.length - (firstIndex + lastIndex) + 1);
      
      if (result === -1 || operations < result) {
        result = operations;
      }
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}


var str = 'abcda';
console.log('result = ', testNumberOfOperations(str));


var str = 'abcdefghiab';
console.log('result = ', testNumberOfOperations(str));


var str = 'pqr';
console.log('result = ', testNumberOfOperations(str));

var str = 'bacdefghipalop';
console.log('result = ', testNumberOfOperations(str));
```

Comment: Actually,I want to know whether my recursive concept is right or not and where I'm making mistake to implement it.